# Project for learning

Tags: react-native

For my learning project, I want to create an app with:

1.settings menu when I can store 3 values. Email, password, and car number.

2. 1 button ( when I open the app and push that button app connects to a web page, logins with email and password after login it should go to search menu on a website enter their car number and then pushes button "pay" when the car is found.

Basically, this app is for paying for parking with 1 click.

The thing is I have the knowledge to build this simple UI and probably I need some sort of database like SQLite to store the settings but how can I do second part? When I push the button that the app connects to www.parking.com(this is not a real webpage), logins and do other staff...

Can someone give me some pointers, examples of similar apps or links where I can find any related information?

Do I need to create some kind of API to connect to the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expo.io to create the app and to perform authentication. Use fetch or axios to access the web page. Use expo api for firebase to store data.

Here is a link to get you started doing authentication  and storing data: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase/